# Parsing C++ decltype() expression into Python via SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to parse a C++ code into Python using SWIG. Running the interface file I get the following error:

../compat/option.hpp:220: Error: Syntax error in input(3).

So this is the code for the line specified

```
template<class F>
auto move_map(F&& f) -> Option<decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::move(*repr.ptr())))>
{
    if (repr.is_some())
        {
            auto rv = Some(std::forward<F>(f)(std::move(*repr.ptr())));
            do_destruct();
            return rv;
        }
    else
        {
            return None;
        }
}
```

I took some time to understand but I finally found that decltype expressions are unsupported yet by SWIG.

http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CPlusPlus11.html#CPlusPlus11_type_inference

So I'm think about any tips on how to strip this code so it could get parsed. I'm not any pro with C++ (actually I'm learning it now) so any help will be welcome.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what your function is meant to do, with a minimal complete example? I'm sure there's a good work around but I don't quite understand your use cases well enough to answer.

Comment: @Flexo I got the same error, just put an `std::unique_ptr<Tcl_Interp, decltype(&Tcl_DeleteInterp)> interp;` in a class and SWIG failed to parse it. I do not even need it to be exported, but the `%ignore` directive is not enough...

Comment: @DarioP %ignore won't work because it's a parse error, not a wrapper error. There is probably a workaround possible, but it needs an MCVE to answer, because  the way to wrap it depends on what you want to do with the function.

Comment: If your reference to %ignore comes from my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30411997/168175 then you missed the most important part of that hack which was the `#define auto` bit.

Comment: @Flexo you are right, the source of the problem is that the argument of `decltype` is an expression. The %ignore came from the top of my head, thanks for the reference to the other question!