# SWIG parser error

Tags: swig

I have following header file.

```
#include <string>

namespace A {
namespace B {

    struct Msg {
        std::string id;
        std::string msg;

        Msg(std::string new_id, std::string new_msg)
        : id(new_id), msg(new_msg)
        {
        }
    };

    template<bool HAS_ID>
    class ID {
    public:
        template<typename TOBJ>
        auto get(TOBJ parent) -> decltype(parent.id()) {
            return parent.id();
        }
    };   
} // namespace B
} // namespace A
```

When i swig it, it gives me an error

`Error: Syntax error in input(3).` at line 20 pointing to line

`auto get(TOBJ parent) -> decltype(parent.id())`

Target language is Java

How can i fix this problem? I only want to create wrapper for Msg struct and for nothing else in the header. As this looks like a Swig parser error, using %ignore directive does not seem to work.

Thank you

Comment: which swig version ?

Comment: @malat Swig version is 3.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although SWIG 3.x added limited `decltype` support it looks like the case you have is unsupported currently. (See [`decltype` limitations](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/CPlusPlus11.html#CPlusPlus11_type_inference))

I think the best you'll get for now is to surround the offending code in preprocessor macros to hide it, e.g.:

```
#include <string>

namespace A {
namespace B {

    struct Msg {
        std::string id;
        std::string msg;

        Msg(std::string new_id, std::string new_msg)
        : id(new_id), msg(new_msg)
        {
        }
    };

    template<bool HAS_ID>
    class ID {
    public:
#ifndef SWIG
        template<typename TOBJ>
        auto get(TOBJ parent) -> decltype(parent.id()) {
            return parent.id();
        }
#endif
    };   
} // namespace B
} // namespace A
```

---

If you can't edit the file like that for whatever reason there are two options:

1. Don't use `%include` with the header file that doesn't parse. Instead write something like:

   ```
   %{
   #include "header.h" // Not parsed by SWIG here though
   %}

   namespace A {
   namespace B {

       struct Msg {
           std::string id;
           std::string msg;

           Msg(std::string new_id, std::string new_msg)
           : id(new_id), msg(new_msg)
           {
           }
       };

   } // namespace B
   } // namespace A

   in your .i file, which simply tells SWIG about the type you want to wrap and glosses over the one that doesn't work.
   ```
2. Alternatively get creative with the pre-processor and find a way to hide it using a bodge, inside your .i file you could write something like:

   ```
   #define auto // \
   void ignore_me();

   %ignore ignore_me;
   ```

   Another similar bodge would be to hide the contents of `decltype` with:

   ```
   #define decltype(x) void*
   ```

   Which just tells SWIG to assume all decltype usage is a void pointer. (Needs SWIG 3.x and could be combined with %ignore which ought to do the ignore, or a typemap to really fix it)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to build wrapper for a library that already exists with the given header file installed in the system so I may not be able to edit it. Is there another work around? Thank you

Comment: @sujithvm even though the library already exists nothing forces you to show SWIG the real header files from the library in your interface.